# Importing SKScene leads to Lexical/Preprocessor Issue

Tags: ios, xcode

Whenever I import any SKScene.sks file into my SKScene controller, it generates a Lexical/Preprocessor issue. I've tried creating multiple different SKScene.sks files and multiple SKScene controllers.

For instance, in my Level1.mm file (I've also tried with .m's and the same thing happens):

```
#import "Level1.h"
#import "SceneOne.sks"
```

Is all it takes to break the game. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#import` directive is a preprocessor instruction to treat the contents of the file following that directive as if it exists in the same file as the rest of the `*.m` file that includes it. Usually, you are importing a header file in order to access the methods defined in it within your calling class. When you compile your code, the compiler will treat your code as if the code in the file you import is literally in the same file.

The reason you are getting a lexical error is that by importing a `.sks` file you are inserting the contents of that file within your source code (literally inserting it, not linking to it). The compiler is trying to read `Objective-C` but the first thing you feed to it is a bug chunk of the `.sks` file (which is actually a binary file) and the compiler doesn't know how to read that.

You need to actually load the file in your code and unarchive this binary object into a concrete class - something like:

```
NSString *scenePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyScene" ofType:@"sks"];
SKScene *scene = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:scenePath];
```